# How to mix WebForms and MVC in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an existing ASP.NET WebForms 3.0 application that works just fine. I upgraded it to ASP.NET 4 and it still works great, but now I want to add some ASP.NET MVC pages to it. I don't want to rewrite the application.

Any suggestions? Can I mix them? How to work it? Any tutorials for me?

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at Scott Hanselman's blog article on this very topic:

[Integrating ASP.NET MVC 3 into existing upgraded ASP.NET 4 Web Forms applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Comment: This advice might be obsolete with ASP.NET 4.  I'm searching for it but haven't found it yet.  I know Scott now talks about how Microsoft now recommends mixing them together in the same project.

I think his article might still work -- it's definitely worth a try.   But MVC 4 changes a few things about the web project initialization so his old blog post might break in a few places.

Answer (score 4):

You have to mention this line of code in the Global.asax file in the MVC application.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{WebPage}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

This disables the MVC routing for the files of extension .aspx

Comment: Thanks all~~is work for me. but how do i call the MVC application page in Asp.net webform application? 
since Url link and Html link is not valid under .net html page..
any example..?

Comment: You can use `<%=ResolveUrl("~/{controller}/{action}/")%>` in your anchor links. Substiture {controller} with your controller name and {action} with your action name. eg.: `<%=ResolveUrl("~/home/index/")%>`